Trying to get System.out.println() to appear in Maven test output
I'm attempting to figure out why some of my JUnit tests are hanging while upgrading from Java 8 to 11. Using System.out.println() inside of the test class works just as expected, placing the out into maven's output stream when using
This is where the test hangs:
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  System.out.println("Before");
  wmsDimensionCalculator = new WMSDimensionCalculator(capabilitiesManager);
  when(capabilitiesManager.getDimensionMap()).thenReturn(createDimensionMap());
  System.out.println("Between whens");
  when(capabilitiesManager.getCombinedCapabilities()).thenReturn(WmsCapabilitiesConverter.unmarshal(MOCK_CAPABILITIES_XML));
  System.out.println("End of before");
}

It will print out Before and Between Whens but won't get to End of before. So what I was trying to do is place System.out.print's in the methods being called in that second when:
@Override
public WMSCapabilites getCombinedCapabilities() {
  System.out.println("WMS Capabilities");
  <lots of unnecessary code to the question> 
}

Essentially this system out won't print anywhere that I can find. It doesn't go to the maven output, it doesn't seem to go into a surefire report.
-will put pom here when able to-
-Dsurefire.useFile=False

Something seems to be causing an infinite loop or something inside of the actual class method being called though and attempting to figure out where I have to use SOut to figure out where and why. But when placing SOut in the actual java class the test is for doesn't place it into Mavens output. I'm not exactly sure how to get this to work or if it is even possible.
Have attempted to place System.out.println() method in class methods to dump info but nothing is displayed.

First an example of such case would be very helpfull... second you should show the pom file, JDK version you are using.. Maven version, Plugin Versions etc. System.out.println is not printend out by default in surefire ...Also I would suggest to check: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile
